# Passing raw SQL to Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I need to display a large amount of data that I don't want paginated because I'm using a jQuery tablesorter, and using `Person.objects.all()` in a view is very expensive for the database. Takes too long to load, so I'm trying to perform raw SQL in my view.

I tried using Django's generic views, but they were just as slow as the `objects.all()` method.

Here are my models. Essentially, I want to display all persons while counting how many times they have appeared in, say, `var1` or `var2`.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64,)
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Object(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    var1 = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name="var1_apps", blank=True, null=True)
    var2 = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name="var2_apps", blank=True, null=True)
    var3 = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name="var3_apps", blank=True, null=True)
    # ...   
    slug = models.SlugField()

from django.db import connection
    def test (request):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM objects_person')
        persons = cursor.fetchall() # fetchall() may not be the right call here?
        return render_to_response('test.html', {'persons':persons}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template:

```
           <table class="table tablesorter">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Var1</th>
                   <th>Var2</th>
                   <th>Var3</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                       {% for person in persons %}
                   <tr>
                       <td><a href="{{ person.get_absolute_url }}">{{  person.last_name }}{% if person.name %}, {{ person.name }}{% endif %}</a></td>
                       <td>{{ person.var1_apps.count }}</td>
                       <td>{{ person.var2_apps.count }}</td>
                       <td>{{ person.var3_apps.count }}</td>
                   </tr>
               {% endfor %}
               </tbody>
           </table>
```

What it does it iterate blank lines, but if I just call `{{ creator }}` it will show the entire SQL table -- which I do not want. I must be doing something wrong with the query, so any help appreciated.

Comment: It can sound surprising, but `.all()` translates exactly to `SELECT * FROM ...` (in your case). So I don't understand what are you trying to do, you optimize nothing at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the `Person.objects.all()`. When you loop through that queryset, you are doing three queries for *every* item in the queryset to calculate the counts.

The answer is to [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) your queryset with the counts for each field.

```
# in the view
persons = Person.objects.annotate(num_var1_apps=Count('var1_apps'),
                                  num_var2_apps=Count('var2_apps'),
                                  num_var3_apps=Count('var3_apps'),
                                  )

# in the template
{% for person in persons %}
               <tr>
                   <td><a href="{{ person.get_absolute_url }}">{{  person.last_name }}{% if person.name %}, {{ person.name }}{% endif %}</a></td>
                   <td>{{ person.num_var1_apps }}</td>
                   <td>{{ person.num_var2_apps }}</td>
                   <td>{{ person.num_var3_apps }}</td>
               </tr>
{% end for %}
```

Comment: Oh, much faster. It is now showing unusually high numbers, though, so I'm not sure what's up with that.

Comment: Oh, had to add `distinct=True` to the `Count` (but it seems noticeably slower after I added it?). Thanks!